# How ResultFilters in .net core updates the IActionResult before the controller return the output?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In Microsoft documentation [ResultFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#result-filters) described on how we can update the response before controller returns. But can anyone explain how it update the IActionResult before the controller returns the response with a small example please?

Comment: Is something wrong with the existing examples on the documentation page you linked to?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar not at all, I just wanted get a clear picture on how the ResultFilter updated the context

Comment: You might also want to look into how `IActionResult` works (if you don't already know). It basically has an "Execute" method (I forget the exact name) inside and that populates the response.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar found the answer, please have a look on my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

When use `OnResultExecutionAsync` method, the response is already bind to the `context.Result`. So that, we can easily use a cast `var objectResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;` and manipulate the response using `objectResult`  as we needed and then set the `context.Result = objectResult` back again. So it would capture by the controller.